# Is there a way with CDK to grant S3 access to a user authenticated with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

With CDK I'm trying to create :

- A private S3 bucket encrypted using KMS
- A Cognito user pool used in a VueJS front running on Amplify

I have both but I can't find a way to grant an authenticated user the right to upload a file to my bucket.

I've seen the [Amplify doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js#using-amazon-s3) stating that I have to create an Auth_Role that grants signed-in-user-level access to the bucket, I tried it using `CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment` but without success, I keep getting 403.

Here is my CDK :

```js
    // KMS
    const ClientKmsKey = new kms.Key(this, 'ClientMasterKey', { trustAccountIdentities: true });


    // Encrypted Bucket
    const test_bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'bucket-name', {
      bucketName: 'bucket-name',
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS,
      encryptionKey: ClientKmsKey,
      cors: [
        {
          allowedHeaders: [
            "*"
          ],
          allowedMethods: [
            s3.HttpMethods.POST,
            s3.HttpMethods.PUT,
            s3.HttpMethods.GET,
          ],
          allowedOrigins: [
            "*"
          ],
          exposedHeaders: [
            'x-amz-server-side-encryption',
            'x-amz-request-id',
            'x-amz-id-2',
            'ETag'
          ],
        }
      ],
    });

    // Identity Pool
    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'AppFrontUserPool', {
      userPoolName: "AppFrontUserPool",
      selfSignUpEnabled: false,
      signInAliases: {
          email: true,
          phone: false,
          username: false
      }
    });

    const userPoolClient = userPool.addClient('app-client', 
    {
      oAuth: {
        flows : {
          implicitCodeGrant: true
        },
        scopes: [OAuthScope.OPENID, ],
        callbackUrls: ['...']
      }
    });

    const identityPool = new cognito.CfnIdentityPool(this, 'app-identity-pool', {
      allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false,
      cognitoIdentityProviders: [{
          clientId: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
          providerName: userPool.userPoolProviderName,
      }]
    });


    // Role for authenticated Users
    const authenticatedRole = new iam.Role(this, 'CognitoDefaultAuthenticatedRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
          "StringEquals": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": identityPool.ref },
          "ForAnyValue:StringLike": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated" },
      }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"),
    });
    authenticatedRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          "s3:*",
          "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
          "mobileanalytics:GetEvents",
          "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        resources: [
          '*'
        ],
    }));

    // Role for UNauthenticated Users
    const unauthenticatedRole = new iam.Role(this, 'CognitoDefaultUnauthenticatedRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
          "StringEquals": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": identityPool.ref },
          "ForAnyValue:StringLike": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated" },
      }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"),
    });
    unauthenticatedRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
      actions: [
        "s3:*",
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "mobileanalytics:GetEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "cognito-identity:*"
      ],
      resources: [
        '*'
      ],
    }));

    const defaultPolicy = new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, 'DefaultValid', {
        identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
        roles: {
            'unauthenticated': unauthenticatedRole.roleArn,
            'authenticated': authenticatedRole.roleArn
        }
    });
```

I used this post to create the Cognito policy :
[How to create Cognito IdentityPool with Cognito UserPool as one of the Authentication provider using aws cdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784746/how-to-create-cognito-identitypool-with-cognito-userpool-as-one-of-the-authentic)

I can't find a way to check if my custom roles are really attached to an authenticated user in the console.

Is there something else I can do ? Can I check in the console that my user pool in Cognito is really using my policy ?

Edit:

This is how I tried to call the S3 bucket with Amplify :

The configuration only specify the bucket and the region.

```js
Storage.get('test_amplify.txt', { level: 'public',  ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms', SSEKMSKeyId: '...'})
        .then (result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
Storage.put('test_from_front.txt', 'HELLO !', { level: 'public',  ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms', SSEKMSKeyId: '...'})
        .then (result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
 

Storage.get('test_amplify.txt', { level: 'public' })
        .then (result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
Storage.put('test_from_front.txt', 'HELLO !')
        .then (result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Still 403

Answer (score 0):

You must grant permissions to the authenticated and unauthenticated roles for the kms key.

Something similar to this:

```js
    // Grant kms permissions
    authenticatedRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          'kms:Decrypt',
          'kms:Encrypt',
          'kms:DescribeKey',
          'kms:ReEncrypt*',
          'kms:GenerateDataKey*',
        ],
        resources: ['*'],
      })
    )

    // Grant decrypt for authenticatedRole role
    ClientKmsKey.grantDecrypt(
      new iam.ArnPrincipal(authenticatedRole.roleArn)
    )

    // Grant kms permissions
    unAuthenticatedRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          'kms:Decrypt',
          'kms:Encrypt',
          'kms:DescribeKey',
          'kms:ReEncrypt*',
          'kms:GenerateDataKey*',
        ],
        resources: ['*'],
      })
    )

    // Grant decrypt for unAuthenticatedRole role
    ClientKmsKey.grantDecrypt(
      new iam.ArnPrincipal(unAuthenticatedRole.roleArn)
    )
```

Useful links:

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decrypt-kms-encrypted-objects-s3/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

I hope it is useful for you.

@fkone